# images to open modal

Tags: javascript, html, web, modal-dialog

i have some images in rows and columns that i want to open a modal when they are clicked. so far only the first image will open the modal and i cant for the life of me figure out why it doesnt work for all of the others code below:

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="Assets/Images/homepage-section-image.png" class="modal" id="modal">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="Assets/Images/homepage-section-image.png" class="modal" id="modal">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="Assets/Images/homepage-section-image.png" class="modal" id="modal">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="Assets/Images/homepage-section-image.png" class="modal" id="modal">
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
const modal_open = document.getElementById('modal');

modal_open.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById("my_modal").style.display = "block";
});
```

'''

Comment: Only one unique `#id` is allowed

Answer (score 0):

Well its because getElementById returns only one element with the given id in your case only the first one. Maybe try the following.

```js
const clicker = () => {

 //get htmlCollection of the img elements by class name 
const imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

//iterate over the images and add an event listener 
    for(let img of imgs){
        img.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert("clicked!")
        });
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    clicker()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <img src="{src}" class="modal" id="modal">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <img src="{src}" class="modal" id="modal">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <img src="{src}" class="modal" id="modal">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <img src="{src}" class="modal" id="modal">
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ofc insted of alert('clicked') add

```
document.getElementById("my_modal").style.display = "block";
```